# SwiftUI: ViewModifier doesn't listen to onReceive events

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a custom `ViewModifier` which simply returns the same content attached with a `onReceive` modifier, the `onReceive` is not triggered, here is a sample code that you can copy, paste and run in `XCode`:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myProperty: Bool = false
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
        .modifier(MyOnReceive(viewModel: viewModel))
            .onTapGesture {
                self.viewModel.myProperty = true
        }
    }
}

struct MyOnReceive: ViewModifier {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MyViewModel

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onReceive(viewModel.$myProperty) { theValue in
                print("The Value is \(theValue)") // <--- this is not executed
        }
    }
}
```

is `SwiftUI` designed to disallow `onReceive` to execute inside a `ViewModifier` or is it a bug ? I have a view in my real life project that gets bigger with some business logic put inside `onReceive`, so I need to clean that view by separating it from `onReceive`.

Comment: Applying the view model pattern in SwiftUI is very bad practice

Comment: @malhal SwiftUI works naturally with this pattern

Comment: Sorry it is not the right pattern. Hopefully my answer to your question here puts you back on the right track with SwiftUI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63782397/swiftui-using-different-property-wrappers-for-the-same-variable/70012628#70012628

Comment: @malhal thank you for your clarification in that answer

Comment: Interesting pattern. I stumbled accidentally over this. I use a similar pattern, where a ViewModifier requires a kind of "VieModel" (you can name it "Store", or AppState or however you want) or let's say it's some actor which receives external events (no user intents!), performs some logic based on its state and the event, and then publishes a state which determine whether or not one of several sheets will be presented and if, with which content.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ok, this works for me:

```
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .onAppear()   // <--- this makes it work
        .onReceive(viewModel.$myProperty) { theValue in
            print("-----> The Value is \(theValue)") // <--- this will be executed
    }
}
```

Comment: it really works, but I don't understand why, this is considered a workaround I believe.

Comment: I stumbled across this by trial and error. I don't understand it either, and 
I didn't know it was a known workaround.

Comment: if it's ok please upvote the question to grab some attention in future.

Comment: This `.onAppear()` will delay the events from publisher after the view appears.

Answer (score 1):

`ObservableObject` and `@Published` are part of the Combine framework if you aren't using Combine then you shouldn't be using a class for your view data. Instead, you should be using SwiftUI as designed and avoid heavy objects and either put the data in the efficient View data struct or make a custom struct as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyConfig {
    var myProperty: Bool = false

    mutating func myMethod() {
         myProperty = !myProperty
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var config = MyConfig()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
        .onTapGesture {
            config.myMethod()
        }
    }
}
```

Old answer:

Try `onChange` instead

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollview/onchange(of:perform:)

```
.onChange(of: viewModel.myProperty) { newValue in
        print("newValue \(newValue)")
    }
```

But please don't use the View Model object pattern in SwiftUI, try to force yourself to use value types like structs for all your data as SwiftUI was designed. Property wrappers like `@State` will give you the reference semantics you are used to with objects.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but just so people know, `onChange` requires the publisher to be `Equatable` otherwise it won't work.

Comment: This answer isn't remotely connected to the OP's question. I understand the OPs setup as a simplification to illustrate his real problem, which usually is much more complex. Your answer tries to show how to apply oversimplification to real problems, which is an attempt which will fail in practice.

Comment: Please stop trying to teach people MVVM in SwiftUI, it's totally wrong

Comment: @CouchDeveloper please read https://azamsharp.com/2022/07/17/2022-swiftui-and-mvvm.html