# SwiftUI: Using different property wrappers for the same variable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

in iOS13 I do the following to bind my View to my model:

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var someVar: String = "initial value"
}

struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = MyModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("the value is \(model.someVar)")
    }
}
```

in iOS14 there is a new property wrapper called `@StateObject` that I can use in the place of `@ObservedObject`, I need this snippet of code to be compatible with iOS13 and iOS14 while leveraging iOS14's new feature, how can I do that with `@StateObject` for the same variable ?

Comment: Unless Apple changes the compatibility of `@StateObject` before release it will not work on iOS 13. You have to stick with your original setup because `@ObservedObject` works with both.

Answer (score 1):

Different property wrappers generate different types of hidden properties, so you cannot just conditionally replace them. Here is a demo of possible approach.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14 (deployment target 13.6)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            MyNewView()
        } else {
            MyView()
        }
    }
}

class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var someVar: String = "initial value"
}

@available(iOS, introduced: 13, obsoleted: 14, renamed: "MyNewView")
struct MyView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model = MyModel()

    var body: some View {
        CommonView().environmentObject(model)
    }
}

@available(iOS 14, *)
struct MyNewView: View {

    @StateObject var model = MyModel()

    var body: some View {
        CommonView().environmentObject(model)
    }
}

struct CommonView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MyModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("the value is \(model.someVar)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ObservableObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject) and [`@Published`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published) are part of the Combine framework and you should only use those when you require a Combine pipeline to `assign` the output to the `@Published` var. What you should be using for your data is `@State` use it as follows:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State var text = "initial value"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("the value is \(text)")
            TextField("", text: $text)
        }
    }
}
```

If you have multiple vars or need functions then you should refactor these into their own struct. Multiple related properties in their own struct makes the View more readable, can maintain invariance on its properties and be tested independently. And because the struct is a value type, any change to a property, is visible as a change to the struct (Learn this in [WWDC 2020 Data Essentials in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/) ). Implement as follows:

```
struct MyViewConfig {
    var text1 = "initial value"
    var text2 = "initial value"

    mutating func reset(){
        text1 = "initial value"
        text2 = "initial value"
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @Binding var config: MyViewConfig
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("the value is \(config.text1)")
            TextField("", text: $config.text1)
            Button("Reset", action: reset)
        }
    }

    func reset() {
        config.reset()
    }
}

struct ContentView {
    @State var config = MyViewConfig()
    var body: some View {
        MyView(config:$config)
    }
}
```

SwiftUI is designed to take advantage of value semantics where all the data is in structs which makes it run super fast. If you unnecessarily create objects then you are slowing it all down.

To answer the question, that use of ObservableObject to init is in correct. Every time the View struct is init a new object will also be init which will slow down SwiftUI. You’ll need to either use a global var or singleton to store the objects and use onAppear to init and onDissapear to destroy. In the WWDC video where StateObject is introduced you’ll hear him say “you don’t need to mess with onDissapear anymore” so that is your clue on how to simulate StateObject. By the way, it is totally fine to update your app with new features only available in the new OS, users that have not yet updated their OS will just stay on the old version of the app and is a much simpler way to work.

Comment: thank you so much for clarifying the idea behind the right usage of `State/Binding` vs `Published/ObservableObject/Observed` I also watched parts of the WWDC video of Dataflow Through SwiftUI that talks exactly about that. However, for the example in the question's text, using MVVM pattern is incorrect and you explained that in the answer, but do you say that the use of MVVM is a bad practice with SwiftUI (in general) ? I use `Observable/Observed/Published` property wrappers in cases that need combine to tell the view to redraw once the data comes in, this is where MVVM is the best choice.

Comment: for the question, I'm sorry I didn't clarify it well, what I need is something like:  `#if  available(iOS 14)   @StateObject var model = MyModel() #else  @ObservedObject var model = MyModel()  #end` I want to use different property wrappers depending on the system's version.

Comment: The use you describe of Combine’s ObservableObjects for downloading data is correct but that is not MVVM. In that case the objects are called Loaders. See CoverImageLoader at 20mins in the video.

Comment: Added info to answer about property wrappers depending on OS version.

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer. I always thought that Loaders pattern is actually MVVM, do you have a link to a SwiftUI code sample that is a true MVVM ? I know I can google it, but a lot of tutorials out there say they are MVVM but they actually are not.

Comment: No MVVM is not compatible with SwiftUI and actually trying to use view model objects instead of using View structs and the body method correctly will break a lot of its magic. It’s not all the MVVM crowds fault though, Apple haven’t done a great job of explaining how all the magic works yet. Eg not many know that when you use a Text and a formatter, it will automatically reformat the UILabel on screen when the user’s region settings change.

Comment: If someone used MVVM and a view model object then they would need to subscribe to the locale notification themselves and manually use the formatter to get a new string, ie do it the way you would with standard UIKit View Controllers, which hardly anyone realised they needed to do. Just think of SwiftUI View structs solving the same problem MVVM tried so solve so it is no longer necessary and just skip it completely and use pure SwiftUI.

Comment: I got it now, thank you for this thorough explanation. well, as you said, the best natural use of SwiftUI is to use it as is and with Loaders.

Comment: I got 2 comments, (1) in the ContentView you create the config state var and pass it on to MyView, which is against Apple's recommendation, which's to have the state var purpose for simple data types (like String, Int, etc ..) and be private. (2) If I have to create a loader object which has many properties, but only one of those properties I need it to be `@Published` to be listened on in the View, is the best choice for this loader is to create a class that adopts `ObservableObject` protocol ?

Comment: (1) is demonstrated at 4.21 in WWDC 2020 Data essentials in SwiftUI. (2) `ObservableObject` and `@Published` are part of the Combine framework where you use `.assign($&somePublishedVar)` to set the result of the pipeline on the `@Published` that notifies SwiftUI to run the body func. so you should only use those when you want to use CombineLatest, Zip or Merge etc. The best choice for loader nowadays is using Async/await's `Task{}` or `.task(id:property)` e.g. `self.someState = await someAsyncFunc`. The async func can be outside of the View struct so it can be tested independently.

Comment: that means, if I want to use `async-await` approach instead of `Combine` in my codebase, then I shouldn't use `@ObservableObject / @ObservedObject / @StateObject` at all in my code and let the `Views` reflect the changes only through `@State` vars ? if that's true, why to deprive myself from the goodies of some `Combine's` sugar like the ones mentioned above ?

Comment: @JaHelia do not listen to malhal please. His advice is undocumented and heavily opinionated. 
SwiftUI is extremely flexible, and can suit a wide range of usages.
Go ahead and use it however you like, and yes you SHOULD use StateObject and ObservedObject as needed, as well as ObservableObject and `Published`.

Comment: @magnuskahr he tries to stick with Apple docs and thoughts and what they say in WWDC sessions, I guess he should think out of the box regarding SwiftUI and its implications.

Comment: He does a very poor job then.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state-and-data-flow