# Passed in published property not firing onReceive in iOS 14 but is in iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I have a view modifier with a publisher passed to it:

```
struct MyViewModifier: ViewModifier {
  let publisher: Published<Bool>.Publisher
  
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .onReceive(publisher) { value in
        print("received") // Never gets called
      }
  }
}

extension View {
  func listen(
    to publisher: Published<Bool>.Publisher
  ) -> some View {
    ModifiedContent(
      content: self,
      modifier: MyViewModifier(
        publisher: publisher
      )
    )
  }
}
```

this is attached to the view as such:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoadingView: View {
  @ObservedObject var model: MyModel

  var body: some View {
    Text("test")
        .listen(
          to: model.$publisher
        )
        
    }
  }
}
```

`publisher` is defined as a `@Published` value inside `MyModel`, which is an `ObservableObject`.

I'm creating `MyModel` and passing it in like this:

```
final class MyViewController: UIHostingController<LoadingView> {
  let model: MyModel

  init() {
    model = LoadingModel()
    super.init(rootView: LoadingView(model: model))
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  }

  @MainActor required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  func togglePublisher(on: Bool) {
    model.publisher = on
  }
}
```

Whenever the value of `model.publisher` is changed this does not get picked up in the `onReceive` modifier in iOS 14. However, this works fine in iOS 16. Why?!

Comment: How are you creating `MyModel` and `LoadingView`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor Updated my question to show you how

Comment: [SwiftUI: ViewModifier doesn't listen to onReceive events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190398/swiftui-viewmodifier-doesnt-listen-to-onreceive-events) might solve your issue as well.

Comment: @DávidPásztor That answer of using `.onAppear()` before `onReceive` worked! Thanks